# Profiling valid for parallel efficiency study?

Tags: unix, time, parallel-processing, fortran, gprof

I have been puzzled by the following matter:

I am trying to check the weak scaling of an in-house parallel Fortran code. Initially I tried to utilise the time command, but I would receive significant higher `real` times than the `sys+user` times. So, I ended up using gprof to perform the time measuring (although it may slow down the execution).

Is gprof a valid approach for benchmarking parallel efficiency (considering it is not ideal approach)?

Comment: Please ask one question per post. And find a post title that describes the question better.

Comment: To figure out the time a program takes to execute use a stopwatch - that way you have to set up tests which take at least a handful of seconds, and you avoid any nonsense with fractions smaller than, say, `0.1s`.  Use `gprof` to help figure out where your program is spending time, but it's not necessary (and may be misleading) for figuring out the scaling performance.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I see what you mean. But using the <time> command isnt effectively like using a stopwatch? and if so, how can the  <real> time be orders higher than the <user+sys> time? Is it my actual code causing this discrepancy? (btw the test cases take at least a few mins)

PS: no user I/O takes place-just outputting on a file